# Changing background image of page by hovering over buttons

Tags: jquery, fade, cross-fade

This is what I got so far: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C7KxR/134/). I've got a background that I want to change to a different image when I hover over a button (and there will be several buttons, several images).

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("#leo_land3_div").hover(function() {
        $("#fish").stop().fadeOut("fast", function() {
            $("#fish").css("background-image", "url('http://i.imgur.com/a0HBqz3.jpg')").fadeIn(700);
        });
    }, function() {
        $("#fish").stop().fadeOut("fast", function() {
            $("#fish").css("background-image", "url('http://i.imgur.com/lJ7Zmi7.jpg')").fadeIn(700);
        });
    });
    });

$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("#leo_land3_div2").hover(function() {
        $("#fish").stop().fadeOut("fast", function() {
            $("#fish").css("background-image", "url('http://i.imgur.com/ThRxyIM.jpg')").fadeIn(700);
        });
    }, function() {
        $("#fish").stop().fadeOut("fast", function() {
            $("#fish").css("background-image", "url('http://i.imgur.com/lJ7Zmi7.jpg')").fadeIn(700);
        });
    });
    });
```

HTML:

```
HTML:

<div id="fish">
<div id="leo_land3_div"><a href="#">TTT</a> </div>
<div id="leo_land3_div2"><a href="#">TTT 3</a> </div>    
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#fish{background-image:url("http://i.imgur.com/lJ7Zmi7.jpg");width:459px;height:474px;}
```

I'm almost there! It works perfectly with a single button. Not so much with two.
The main issue I can't fix is getting the background images to fade to each other, not to "nothing" and then back. Also not sure what is happening when I add another link.

[These guys](http://chilewich.com/) have done exactly what I want, but I don't have the mettle to figure out HOW they did it.

Answer (score 1):

Change your fades to `animate` and set `queue` to false so they run in parallel:

```
.animate(
    { opacity: 0 },
    { queue: false, duration: 'slow' }
  )
```